# CAML Query with contains not working

Tags: caml-query, caml

I have a Multiple Lookupfield on my List (list of document sets)

When I do this query it works and shows me the results on the screenshot:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='ClientCode' />
            <Value Type='Text'>12345678</Value>
         </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='JobsSearchMulti' />
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions />
```

[image]

Now I need to do a query with both client code and job code

like this:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
<And>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ClientCode' />
         <Value Type='Text'>12345678</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Contains>            
         <FieldRef Name='JobsSearchMulti' />            
         <Value Type='JobCascadingLookupMultipleV2'>T005</Value>         
       </Contains>
</And>
   </Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='JobsSearchMulti' />
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions />
```

or this:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
<And>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='ClientCode' />
         <Value Type='Text'>12345678</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Contains>

         <FieldRef Name='JobsSearchMulti' />            
         <Value Type='Text'>T005</Value>         
       </Contains>
</And>
   </Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='JobsSearchMulti' />
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions />
```

It should return results but its not doing it.

Comment: if its a multi-lookup, shouldn't the `Value Type` be `LookupMulti` ? Can you check by modifying it as `<Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='JobsSearchMulti' />            
         <Value Type='LookupMulti'>T005</Value>         
       </Contains>`

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong type and it's been known that CONTAINS is very flaky much like some of the rest of the CAML query language (I'm looking at you recurring events). Using `EQ` here will probably be your best bet. Try this:

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"JobsSearchMulti\" LookupId=\"TRUE\"/><Value Type=\"LookupMulti\">19448</Value></Eq>
```

https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/multi-lookup-fields-in-caml-queries-eq-vs-contains/